# Typescript discriminated union not working properly for a React props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a wrapper component for 2 child components.
Button (Parent) is responsible for rendering one of the child components (block | link). Each child has its own definitions. I want the parent to suggest the correct definition depending on property *type*.

```
const Button: React.FC<ButtonProps> = ({
    type = "block",
    children,
    className,
    hrefType,
    onClick,
    onClickAnimation,
    onHoverAnimation,
    size,
    style,
    variant,
}): JSX.Element => {...}
```

```
type conditionalProps =
    | ({
          type?: "link";
      } & LinkButtonProps)
    | ({
          type?: "block";
      } & BlockButtonProps);

export type ButtonProps = BaseButtonProps & conditionalProps;
```

```
export interface BlockButtonProps extends BaseButtonProps {
    onHoverAnimation?: "jump" | "beat" | "wiggle";
    onClickAnimation?: "none" | "simple";
}
```

```
export interface LinkButtonProps extends BaseButtonProps {
    linkComponent?: JSX.Element;
    onHoverAnimation?: "line";
    onClickAnimation?: "none" | "simple";
}
```

The problem is that both component's properties are merged instead.
[intellisense suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKfsk.png)